# Error templatedoesn'tExist bootstrap4/whole_unit.html when installing django crispy form

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I have installed Django crispy forms as describe to the official site forms have never been this crispy but while opening my template, I got an error templatedoesn'tExist bootstrap4/whole_uni.html.
On the page describing the error, it is mentioned that the error comes from the tag
{% crispy form %}

I tried to search why that error but I didn't find any outcome